# How to find the representation of Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I read a book about the Lie algebra, but I really don't understand the calculation of $ad(X)$. For example, we have a Lie algebra of bases:
$$e_1=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{array}\right], e_2=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{array}\right],  e_3=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\-1 & 0\end{array}\right]$$

I want to know the format of $ad(e_1)$, $ad(e_2)$ and $ad(e_3)$.

All the authors said that "it is clearly that ad(e1)=...,ad(e2)=... and ad(e3)=...", but how did they find it?

another example:
$$e_1=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{array}\right], e_2=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{array}\right], e_3=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{array}\right], e_4=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right].$$
the adjoint representation is 
$$ad(e_1)=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right].$$
Some one said that it has a relationship to the structure constant $C_{ijk}$, but how to write $ad(e)$ with $C_{ijk}$?

Comment: They probably found them by checking what $\rm{ad}(x)$ does to each basis vector for each $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recall that for any $X \in \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$, $\text{ad}_{X}$ is the ***linear operator on the vector space $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$*** that sends every $Y$ in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$ to $\text{ad}_X(Y) = [X,Y]$. Every linear operator on a finite dimensional space can be represented by a matrix. In this case, we want a matrix in the basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as you defined. So if $X = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right)$ then we need to calculate $\text{ad}_X(e_1),\text{ad}_X(e_2)$ and $\text{ad}_X(e_3)$. We find:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \text{ad}_X(e_1) &=& 0\\
\text{ad}_X(e_2) &=& 2e_2 \\
\text{ad}_X(e_3) &=& 2e_3 .\\ \end{eqnarray*}$$

Thus the matrix of $\text{ad}_X$ ***in the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$*** is given by:

$$[\text{ad}_X]_{\mathcal{B}} = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I understand it, that's just a transformation of basis. I'm so stupid...

Comment: There is one another thing I'm not sure. The matrix $adX$ should be considered by the row or the column? for example, we have $$[e_1,e_2]=0,[e_1,e_3]=-e_2,[e_2,e_3]=e_1$$
then $ad_e_1$ should be [0 0 0;0 0 -1;0 0 0] or [0 0 0;0 0 0;0 -1 0]?

Comment: @Martial depends on what basis you choose (or more precisely, what ordering you pick for the basis).

Comment: yes, I know what you mean, here we take this example: the old basis are: $$e_1=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right),e_2=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right),e_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right)$$, and the new basis are $\text{ad}e_1,\text{ad}e_2,\text{ad}e_3$, we have $[e_1,e_2]=0,[e_1,e_3]=-e_2,[e_2,e_3]=e_1$, so what is $\text{ad}e_1$? In the answer, the matrix is luckly diagonal, so I dont know that he did it by column or row.